# How to remove metal ring on flex conduit?

Tags: electrical, conduit

I'm replacing my electric car charging station with a newer version. The current one is fed from behind by flex conduit which is held in place with a metal ring. The ring is featureless and smooth (see photos) so I don't think it twists off. I tried gripping it with pliers and twisting anyway but all that happened was that the conduit turned.

Any idea how I can remove this ring to release the conduit?

Edit: This is in California USA.

[image: wider view][image: View inside]

Comment: The other side of the gray panel can you access it?

Comment: Not without dismounting the whole unit, it is screwed to the wall. I’d rather not do that until I’m ready to install the new unit.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, the ring does not seem to be attached to the grey (plastic) panel, it’s just attached to the conduit, preventing it from passing back through the hole in the panel.

Comment: That is one very precisely drilled hole.

Comment: It’s possible the old charger came with the flexible wiring whip preinstalled.   You might be trying to remove something factory crimped into place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's threaded into the flex conduit. it has ridges on the side of the fitting that match the pitch of the spiral of the flex.

In reality they are not really using that correctly, they are rigging it up using parts that are intended for a different use. Here is the actual assembly that it is part of (the photo is of a stainless steel version, but it's the same concept):

[image]

The part you are looking at on yours is only the chase sleeve, shown in this photo to the left of the blue ring. It is INTENDED to go into a fitting that is sealing against the seal-tite flex. They are using only that sleeve and using it kind of backward.

Comment: It'll unscrew with some channel locks np, assuming you can get a handle on the actual conduit to keep it from turning.

Comment: I’ll see if I can pull it out enough to get a grip with vice grips. Thanks

Comment: No, I did mean the part to the LEFT of the blue ring. As I said it appears they used it in a way it is not intended for. We call that a "hack".

Comment: Turns out you are absolutely correct, it was the part to the left of the blue ring. When I got it out (took some penitrating oil to get it loose) and bought the new full set as you showed, I realized that was indeed it. I’m installed the full water-tight connector in its place.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Yours appears to be snapped in from the other side of panel like this style

Comment: I don’t think so. Mine doesn’t have the prongs on the side, unless what I’m seeing is a cover over the prongs.

Comment: No. Kris means the prongs are **on the side you can't see**.  It's not this type of fitting literally; he's just showing the prongs as a point of illustration.   This is a whip which is installed from this side, the whole whip is threaded through the hole and then *snap*.